# Eclipse plugin- No more handles error while populating outline view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to populate a outline view with keywords/tokens selected from the editor content.
Once a keyword is added a keyword is added in editor it is simultaneously added to outline view at appropriate position then outline is refreshed and expanded.

But when adding multiple lines in large number one after the other, I start getting swt exception: no more handles issue.

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: Show us your code, there is no chance of helping without it.

Comment: Particularly code where you're creating things like Image instances.

Comment: @greg-449 : code is on company server and it cant be shared from there.Thats why I was asking for suggestion as I know that without code actually solution could not be given but if you could provide some pointers it would be great.

Comment: @NickWilson : yes images are also getting created.And it happens only if I am adding code multiple times in quick succession but not when I add complete code in one go.

Comment: You are probably creating lots of `Image` (or other SWT Resource) objects and not calling `dispose` on the object when you are done with it. You **must** dispose of resources when you have finished with them.

Comment: Also for images take a look at the AbstractUIPlugin ImageRegistry as a way to ensure images are only loaded once.

Comment: I think using image registry has solved the issue.Thanks